# React-redux reducer is matching action.type based on position in switch statement

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Any idea why my reducer is acting on action.type based on its position in the switch statement?
I spent a lot of time debugging and then realized it was actually the position in the switch statement that is causing the problem.

```
import {
FETCH_PRODUCTS_BEGIN,
FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
FETCH_PRODUCTS_ERROR,
CREATE_PRODUCT,
UPDATE_PRODUCT,
DELETE_PRODUCT,
} from "./inventoryTypes";

const initialState = {
loading: false,
products: [],
error: "",
};

const userInventoryReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
case FETCH_PRODUCTS_BEGIN:
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: true,
  };
case FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
  return {
    loading: false,
    products: action.payload,
    error: "",
  };
case FETCH_PRODUCTS_ERROR:
  return {
    loading: false,
    products: [],
    error: action.payload,
  };
case DELETE_PRODUCT:
  return {
    ...state,
    products: state.products.filter(
      (product) => product._id !== action.payload
    ),
  };
case CREATE_PRODUCT:
  console.log("your calling create!");
  return {...state}
case UPDATE_PRODUCT:
  console.log("calling update");
  return { ...state };

default:
  return state;
}
};
```

Comment: Can you add the "inventoryTypes" file?

Comment: @Ar26 Yep. It appears i copy-pasted the variable in inventoryTypes and forgot to fix the value. shame. all fix now

Comment: @Ar26 can u post the answer brother so we can close this thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the values inside your `"./inventoryTypes"` file' maybe there are duplications of the same actions.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. The value for my `CREATE_PRODUCT, UPDATE_PRODUCT` inside `"./inventoryTypes"` is the same!